# Save input in plugin as pdf format file

Tags: qgis, python, pdf

I m trying to make QGIS plugin with plugin builder that compare 2 map scale with Input1 and Input2 as input scale and show recommendation after clicked recommendation button.

I wrote my code like this:

```
class conditionDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_condition()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        Recomend = self.ui.btnProc
        QtCore.QObject.connect(Recomend, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compare1)
        RecSec = self.ui.btnProc2
        QtCore.QObject.connect(RecSec, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compare2)
        Smpan = self.ui.btnSave
        QtCore.QObject.connect(Smpan, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.saveAs)       

    def Compare1(self):
        input1 = self.ui.lineInput1.text()
        input2 = self.ui.lineInput2.text()
        compare = ''
        if input1 == input2:
            compare = 'Matching'
        else:
            compare = 'Not Matching'
        self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText(compare)

    def Compare2(self):
        dat1 = self.ui.lineCond1.text()
        dat2 = self.ui.lineCond2.text()
        hitung = ''
        if dat1 == dat2:
            hitung = 'Scale is Matching'
        elif dat1 >= dat2:
            hitung = 'Still can be used'
        else:
            hitung = 'Cannot be used'
        self.ui.textRec2.setPlainText(hitung)

    def _save(self, simpan):       
        f = open( simpan, 'w' )
        f.write( 'Input 1 :' + "%s" % self.ui.lineInput1.text() )
        f.write( 'Input 2 :' + "%s" % self.ui.lineInput2.text() )
        f.write( 'Recomendation :' + (str(compare)+'\n' )
        f.write( 'Data 1 :' + "%s" % self.ui.lineCond1.text() )
        f.write( 'Data 2 :' + "%s" % self.ui.lineCond2.text() )
        f.close()
    def savefile(self):
        if self.simpan:
              self._save( "%s" % self.simpan )
        else:
              self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
            tulis = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
            if tulis !="":
                _filename = "%s" % tulis
                self._save( _filename )
```

What must I add to save it to pdf format?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Python script to to convert your resulting text file in PDF or a Python module to write pdf files and there are many... (look at [PiPY:pdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=Pdf&submit=search)).

#### 1) first solution with a Python script:

- [Text to PDF Converter (rewrite) (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532908/) , for example.

#### 2) second solution with a Python module

The problem is that you need to install the module in the Python used by QGIS (easy in Mac OS X or Linux, difficult in Windows) or in the folder of your plugin.

- the most complete module is [reportlab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab), but it is difficult to use (look at [reportlab-userguide.pdf](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf))
- One of the easiest is the pure Python [PyFPDF](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/) module (it is used by Joel Lawhead in his book, [Learning Geospatial Analysis with Python](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-geospatial-analysis-with-python/book), to produce PDF reports with maps)

```py
def _save(self, simpan):  
    import fpdf
    # Portrait, millimeter units, A4 page size     
    pdf=fpdf.FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")
    # Add our one report page
    pdf.add_page()
    # Set font: Times, normal, size 10
    pdf.set_font('Times','', 10)
    # Layout cell: 0 x 5 mm, text, no border, Left
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 1 : ' + self.ui.lineInput1.text(), border=0, align="L" )
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 2 : ' + self.ui.lineInput2.text(), border=0, align="L")
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Recomendation : ' + (str(compare), border=0, align="L")
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 1 :' +  self.ui.lineCond1.text(), border=0, align="L" )
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 2 :' + self.ui.lineCond2.text(), border=0, align="L" )
    pdf.output( simpan+'.pdf','F')
```

- Another solution is to use the single file [PDFWriter.py](https://bitbucket.org/vasudevram/xtopdf/src/854a19c557af9040d74e23c10fa2a6d108d77c68/PDFWriter.py?at=default) from the [xtopdf](https://bitbucket.org/vasudevram/xtopdf) toolkit (as easy as [PyFPDF](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/), but it requires the [reportlab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab) module) of  [Vasudev Ram](http://jugad2.blogspot.be/) but I do not know if you can use a single file and you must install [reportlab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab)...

```py
def _save(self, simpan):  
    from PDFWriter import PDFWriter
    pw = PDFWriter(simpan+'.pdf')
    pw.setFont("Courier", 10)
    pw.writeLine('Input 1 : ' + self.ui.lineInput1.text() )
    pw.writeLine('Input 2 : ' +  self.ui.lineInput2.text() )
    pw.writeLine('Recomendation :' + (str(compare))
    pw.writeLine('Data 1 : ' +  self.ui.lineCond1.text() )
    pw.writeLine('Data 2 : ' + self.ui.lineCond2.text() )
    pw.close
```

Comment: I forgot `pdf.add_page()` corrected above